# SSIS: pass package password to child package

Tags: ssis

I have a master SSIS package that calls child packages that have ProtectionLevel = EncryptSensitiveWithPassword and a password. When the master tries to to execute a child package, I am prompted for the child package password.

The child packages are in a Sequence Container. Within that definition, there is a "Package Password" property, and I have set that, but it still prompts for the password.  I also notice that there is no settable property for packagepassword in the expressions editor.

I have tried defining the password as a parent variable, but it is not working -- still get prompted for the packagepassword.  So I was thinking about using a SQL Server configuration table, but can not find the proper value to put in the "PackagePath" column.

Or any other suggestions/words of wisdom -- many thanks!

Steve

Comment: First question: do you really need to use `EncryptSensitiveWithPassword`? Do you have tasks in your SSIS that can't use windows type authentication, and have to contain hard coded database passwords?

Comment: This is not a DB password -- it is a Package Password.  And yes, using EncryptSensitiveWithPassword is a shop standard.

Comment: OK: using the PackagePassword does indeed work. It's just that I was testing it with debug, which forces each package to open up, and thus the dialog request for the password.  Running without debug works like a charm.

Comment: The only reason to use EncryptSensitiveWithPassword is if you have DB (or other) passwords in your packages. Thats why I ask. Is there a reason it's a shop standard?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same kind of issue today and just updating that solution here as there is no answer given for this question.

We have to make sure the password has been updated on Master.dtsx --> Execute Package Task Editor (double click on Execute Package Task) --> Packages --> Password.

Enter the same password which you have set for the package and then run the Master package.